# Is it possible to convert a Master-Detail relationship to a Lookup?

Tags: lookup, relationships, master-detail

I'm going through the Trailhead training ([here](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/force_com_introduction/data_modeling/object_relationships)), and see the following two snippets which seem to disagree:

> "**It’s possible to change a lookup relationship to a master-detail
>   relationship, but not the other way around**. Hence, if you’re in doubt
>   which one to use, it’s best to start with a lookup relationship. If
>   you later decide you need the features of a master-detail
>   relationship, you can change it.

And later on the same page I find:

> "If you delete the primary master-detail relationship **or convert it to
>   a lookup relationship**, the secondary master object becomes primary."

These seem at odds to me, so either (1) I'm misunderstanding what it's saying or (2) there is a discrepancy in the documentation.  Which is it?  If I'm just misunderstanding, can someone explain what it really means?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the Salesforce documentation: [Considerations for Relationships](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_considerations.htm)

> **Converting Relationships**
>
> You can convert a master-detail relationship to a lookup relationship
>   as long as no roll-up summary fields exist on the master object.
>
> You can convert a lookup relationship to a master-detail relationship,
>   but only if the lookup field in all records contains a value.

Comment: Then do you think the first quote in my post just plain wrong?  Or just an inaccurate simplification because they haven't gone over roll-up summaries?

Comment: When in doubt, trust the official documentation. Trailhead's statement is without question, incorrect.

Comment: @MarkPond are there any considerations specifically to doing this in a managed package?

Comment: @NSjonas yes there are - in a managed package, the field data type is locked and cannot be changed. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_attributes.htm

Comment: Just a note, the fields have to be **hard deleted**. If they're still in your Recycle Bin you will remain blocked.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is a known issue. Mark Pond is correct, our information in that unit on Trailhead is inaccurate. You can convert as long as there are no RSF fields. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_considerations.htm&language=en_US

We've got the fix teed up and ready to go in our next release.