# Any workaround instead changing Master-Detail to Lookup in Enterprise edition?

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, lookup, master-detail, enterprise

I tried changing the master-detail to look up relationship.. there was no option, when I checked on internet it says only developer edition you can do it, enterprise edition it's not allowed.

Actually This is needed remove the old unused field on a custom object. Since this seems not possible, I'm going to have a dummy record and keep the id of dummy record in a Config setting, and use it while creating new records of custom object.

Anyone has experience with this scenario?
Appreciate any suggestion for a better way of doing this.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never heard about edition affecting on changing master-detail to lookup.
If you googled and checked [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008s4QIAQ), below's written that choosen answer's wrong and it's possible to change master-detail relationship to lookup.

***Usually the only thing that prevents on changing master-detail to lookup is the rollup summaries that are exist on master-side object.***

Check for roll-up summaries on master-side object. Also [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68962/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-master-detail-relationship-to-a-lookup) will explicitly answer you question.